# Add watermark on ffmpeg stream

Tags: ffmpeg

How i can add watermark with text or image on ffmpeg stream ?
This is my command :

```
ffmpeg -re -i "input.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2
    -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv "rtmp://"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1). It would look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "input.mp4" -i "logo.png" -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" 
    -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level 31 -preset slow -b:v 800k -c:a aac
    -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header
    -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv "rtmp://"
```

Comment: Error : "Streamcopy requested for output streaam 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together."

where should i put logo.png ? ffmpeg/bin ?

Comment: Sorry, edited to show how to re-encode the video stream with the overlay. You can have the input file anywhere on the system, and they can be referenced with an absolute path.

Comment: You have an orphaned `-c:v` in your command. Should be removed.